# Detecting when the mouse has 'stopped moving' in JavaFX using FXML

Tags: java, javafx

I want to be able to detect when a the mouse is moving and when it is not moving over an AnchorPane using JavaFX.

I currently have a 'Mouse Moved Event' on my pane that outputs some text when the mouse is moved, but would like to also include some output when the mouse isn't moving.

I am stumped on how I can achieve the second half of the problem while still keeping it relatively simple.

Below outputs "moving" whenever the mouse is moved but when the mouse stops, nothing happens. I can see this is because `checkMovement` is only called when it moves.

Is there such a thing as an inverse function or similar - something that will do the opposite?

I do believe I can achieve what I want using specific event handlers and/or timers, but this overly complicated for something that seems quite simple. 
**Am I missing something totally obvious here??**

I am only quite new to using FX, so feel free to point out anything I should be doing a different way.

**EDIT:**
I did forget to specify that I am using FXML to define the controls.
Do I need to put this process within the controller(AppController.java) or for 'ease-of-use' sake just leave it in Main.java? 
How would I even go about this/is it possible?
Obviously, the `mouseMovementMethod` needs to be modified.

**AppController.Java**

public class AppController implements Initializable{

```
    boolean moved = false;

    @FXML 
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;

    @FXML
    private ImageView killpic;

    @FXML
    private ImageView processpic;

    @FXML
    private Text exit;

   @FXML
   private Button processAnimalButton;

   /*
    * ...Other Variables
    */



    @FXML 
    void mouseMovedMethod(Event event){
        //Mouse Movement Event
    }

    @FXML
    void closeMenu(Event event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) exit.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    void selectProcess(Event event) {
        Image killimg = new Image("/images/knife_blood.png");
        Image proimg = new Image("/images/p_selected.png");
        killpic.setImage(killimg);
        processpic.setImage(proimg);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        Image killimg = new Image("/images/knife_blood_selected.png");
        Image proimg = new Image("/images/p.png");
        killpic.setImage(killimg);
        processpic.setImage(proimg);
    }

}
```

**Main.java:**

```
//*Required imports*//

public class Main extends Application {
    Stage thestage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("popup.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            thestage = primaryStage;    
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time `mouseMoved` is triggered, restart a timer of some sort with a short delay.  When the timer triggers, the mouse will have stopped moving.  You may also want to track mouse exited events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not as simple as you think it should be is that the concept of "mouse not moving" is not as clearly defined as you think it is. The underlying operating system detects input events, such as movement of the mouse, in some deeply buried inner loop. That loop takes a finite time to run, and so the mouse is always apparently stationary for the time it takes the loop to run. The OS is going to report those movements to the JavaFX toolkit with some reduced frequency, and the JavaFX toolkit potentially limits the reporting time of those still further.

Consequently, to define "mouse not moving", you really have to resort to "no mouse movement has been detected in the last `x`", where `x` is some measure of time (either real time, e.g. nanoseconds, or number of frame renderings). So you really have to actually implement the logic for that somehow, and decide on how much time counts as "not moving".

@MadProgrammer suggests one implementation in the comments (which I think is the simpler one), and @Roland suggests another.

Here's an implementation of @MadProgrammer's suggestion:

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TrackMouseStopped extends Application {

    private final long MIN_STATIONARY_TIME = 100_000_000 ; // nanoseconds 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        BooleanProperty mouseMoving = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        mouseMoving.addListener((obs, wasMoving, isNowMoving) -> {
           if (! isNowMoving) {
               System.out.println("Mouse stopped!");
           }
        });

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(MIN_STATIONARY_TIME / 1_000_000));
        pause.setOnFinished(e -> mouseMoving.set(false));

        // Note: if you want to consider the mouse having moved for
        // other events (e.g. dragging), you can do
        // pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> { ... }); here
        pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            mouseMoving.set(true);
            pause.playFromStart();
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and here's an implementation of @Roland's suggestion:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TrackMouseStopped extends Application {

    private final long MIN_STATIONARY_TIME = 100_000_000 ; // nanoseconds 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseLocation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Point2D(0, 0));
        pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> mouseLocation.set(new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY())));

        BooleanProperty mouseMoving = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        mouseMoving.addListener((obs, wasMoving, isNowMoving) -> {
           if (! isNowMoving) {
               System.out.println("Mouse stopped!");
           }
        });

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            private double lastMouseX ;
            private double lastMouseY ;
            long lastMouseMovement ;
            @Override
            public void handle(long timestamp) {
                double x = mouseLocation.get().getX();
                double y = mouseLocation.get().getY();
                if (Double.doubleToLongBits(lastMouseX) != Double.doubleToLongBits(x)
                    || Double.doubleToLongBits(lastMouseY) != Double.doubleToLongBits(y)) {
                    lastMouseMovement = timestamp ;
                }

                mouseMoving.set(timestamp - lastMouseMovement < MIN_STATIONARY_TIME);

                lastMouseX = x;
                lastMouseY = y;
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: marking this answer as accepted as it provides implementation for both approaches. Roland and MadProgrammer's methods are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Event listener of [MouseEvent.ANY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#ANY). In that event listener you set your own properties mouseX and mouseY to the mouse location values of the event. In addition to that create an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) which runs permanently and checks if the mouse coordinates didn't change within an interval of "delta" ms. If they didn't, invoke your handling code.

Example:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    Scene scene;
    MouseStatus mouseStatus = new MouseStatus();

    Label infoLabel;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        infoLabel = new Label();
        root.getChildren().add( infoLabel);

        scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        addInputListeners();

    }


    private void addInputListeners() {

        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {

            infoLabel.setText("Moving");

            mouseStatus.setX(e.getX());
            mouseStatus.setY(e.getY());
            mouseStatus.setPrimaryButtonDown(e.isPrimaryButtonDown());
            mouseStatus.setSecondaryButtonDown(e.isSecondaryButtonDown());

        });

        AnimationTimer loop = new AnimationTimer() {

            long deltaNs = 30_000_000;

            double currX;
            double currY;
            long currNs;

            double prevX;
            double prevY;
            long prevNs;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                currX = mouseStatus.x;
                currY = mouseStatus.y;
                currNs = now;

                if( currNs - prevNs > deltaNs) {

                    if( prevX == currX && prevY == currY) {
                        infoLabel.setText("Stopped");
                    }

                    prevX = currX;
                    prevY = currY;
                    prevNs = currNs;
                }

            }
        };
        loop.start();

    }



    public class MouseStatus {

        double x;
        double y;
        boolean primaryButtonDown;
        boolean secondaryButtonDown;

        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public void setX(double x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public void setY(double y) {
            this.y = y;
        }
        public boolean isPrimaryButtonDown() {
            return primaryButtonDown;
        }
        public void setPrimaryButtonDown(boolean primaryButtonDown) {
            this.primaryButtonDown = primaryButtonDown;
        }
        public boolean isSecondaryButtonDown() {
            return secondaryButtonDown;
        }
        public void setSecondaryButtonDown(boolean secondaryButtonDown) {
            this.secondaryButtonDown = secondaryButtonDown;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I was just testing that idea when you posted this. Unless I'm missing a way to do it, it turns out to be quite a bit trickier than @MadProgrammer's suggestion.

Comment: @James_D: added Example. Which timer would you use that's being started over and over? Of course, that's valid too, but personally I prefer the continuity of the AnimationTimer. Btw, MadProgrammer's solution doesn't consider e. g. the mouse being pressed while moving, i. e. dragging.

Comment: Added examples: sorry, just cross-posted with yours, wasn't intending to steal the idea. A `PauseTransition` is the simplest thing to use as a timer. Using `MouseEvent.ANY` is a good option, assuming that's the functionality required.

Comment: No problem. Yours is very compact. I've been using mine for quite some time now with Particle stuff, Painting on Canvas, etc. Among mouse locations i needed e. g. the mouse buttons being pressed and what not. So for me it was just copy/paste. One may of course remove the redundant code.

Comment: @James_D , @Roland: See edit - I am using fxml for structure. As I explicitly defined `onMouseMoved="#mousedMovedMethod"` within this, I have a controller which contains this method - as specified in: 
    `pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {`
             `mouseMoving.set(true);`
             `pause.playFromStart();`
        `});`
of @James_D's implementation of @MadProgrammers solution.

I have tried migrated the code over, and had it mostly working however when executing, it was `System.out.Println()`ing 5 or more consecutive times for each `if` statement.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if you're using FXML. The examples posted are just standalone examples for convenience. Just do the initialisation work in the `initialize()` method.